# How parse microsoft xml with php

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-parsing

I try parse xml receiving from server with function simplexml_load_string(), but I receive parse error. Is another way to parse this xml?
`print_r($result1->GetChannelMeasurementResul->any)`  give:

`<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Measurements" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="Measurements"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="Station" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="ChannelID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="DateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="Value" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="Status" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><DocumentElement xmlns=""><Measurements diffgr:id="Measurements1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><Station>12</Station><ChannelID>6</ChannelID><DateTime>2021-06-04T18:10:00+02:00</DateTime><Value>13.77392</Value><Status>0</Status></Measurements><Measurements diffgr:id="Measurements2" msdata:rowOrder="1"><Station>12</Station><ChannelID>6</ChannelID><DateTime>2021-06-04T18:11:00+02:00</DateTime><Value>13.77652</Value><Status>0</Status></Measurements><Measurements diffgr:id="Measurements3" msdata:rowOrder="2"><Station>12</Station><ChannelID>6</ChannelID><DateTime>2021-06-04T18:12:00+02:00</DateTime><Value>13.77884</Value><Status>0</Status></Measurements></DocumentElement></diffgr:diffgram>`

I try with

`$result1 = $client->__soapCall('GetChannelMeasurement', array( $measerement)); $results2=simplexml_load_string($result1->GetChannelMeasurementResult->any);`

Comment: Can you share with us your code which you have tried?

Comment: The code you post looks like the raw response from the server. simplexml_load_string() is meant for dealing with a clean XML file.

Comment: I try with                                                                                                                                         ``` $result1 = $client->__soapCall('GetChannelMeasurement', array( $measerement));
$results2=simplexml_load_string($result1->GetChannelMeasurementResult->any);```

Comment: It may be the return value from `GetChannelMeasurementResult->any` isn't what you are after.  What does `print_r($result1->GetChannelMeasurementResult);` give?

Comment: xml in first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the string you've pasted, you'll see that it doesn't start and end with the same tag, which a valid XML document always will. That's presumably what the parse error you got said, but you didn't post the full message (tip for future: **always** post the error message; when if it means nothing to you, it might give a clue to someone reading).

It looks like what you're seeing is actually *two* XML documents, one after the other; or possibly the two elements shown are supposed to be wrapped in an outer element, but either your code, or the code on the server, is stripping it off. You could try to look at the raw SOAP response (using SoapClient's "trace" option and __getResponse() method, if I remember the names right) to get a clearer picture.

One possible workaround would be to add a wrapper of your own - `$xml = "<whatever>$xml</whatever>";` - and then parse that.

Comment: thank you for hint. I used different function in I got regular soap                                            xml response `$result = $client->GetChannelMeasurements($measerement);
$result1=$client->__getLastResponse();
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $doc->loadXML( $soapResponse );
    var_dump(doc);
    $XMLresults     = $doc->getElementsByTagName("Measurements");
     $XMLresults     = $doc->getElementsByTagName("Value");
    var_dump($XMLresults);
    $output = $XMLresults->item(2)->nodeValue;`